# Combining UIWindows?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I am going to add 50 windows with 4 UIButtons (with text) and 1 UILabel (with text as well) to EVERY window. Do I need to do it this way? Is there a better way?

Comment: Add 50 UIWindows? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: for the record, don't add 50 UIWindows regardless

Comment: Why do you want to use that many windows? Why cant you use UIViews or controllers?

Comment: I want to create something like "question" - answer

Comment: Question will be in label and answers on 4uibuttons.The main problem that I will have about 50! Questions!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode, so you should remove that tag. And which is it, iOS or OSX? In any case, multiple windows is not the way to go. You don't even need multiple view controllers -- you're just populating some labels, which can be done from an array of questions and answers.

Comment: Why don't you just change the text on the label? Then change the text on the buttons? I imagine that you would like to have one UILabel with a question and four buttons with answers.

Comment: I think he wants to have a panel with fifty questions on screen at once, in which case he should just make a UIView subclass and make an instance for every question. Alternatively he could just manually place the labels and the buttons as subviews of his UIViewController's main view.

Comment: @Metabble yes, maybe. Nmzik - I think you need to study the basics of OOP. I googled a youtube video for you, that might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_SGPe8yC9I

Comment: @Mikael The question IS hard to understand. Even after editing I'm not 100% certain it even means what I think it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a good idea to create additional windows if you can help it, especially on iOS where there is almost never a need to do so. You should create a UIViewController subclass and make it your root view controller (this is already set up in the single view application template). Then, make a subclass of UIView — let's call it "MyQuizView." "MyQuizView" should have a custom initializer that takes five NSStrings (one for the question, four for the answers) and an integer to determine which answer is the correct one. The UIViewController subclass can then instantiate 50 of these views handing them values from the model and make them its main view's subviews.

EDIT: Here's an example of a custom initializer for a UIView subclass.

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame question:(NSString*)ques answers:(NSArray*)ans correctAnswer:(int)correctAns{
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
    if (self) {
        self.question = ques;
        self.answers = ans;
        self.correctAnswerNumber = correctAns;
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
```

A custom initializer starts with `init`. It sets `self` to the return vale of its superclasses' designated initializer, then, if `self` is not nil, it initializes its state–usually using the arguments passed to do so. At the end it returns `self`. This one assumes you have the correct properties and calls a method called `setup` after setting the properties to the correct values, allowing you to use them to create labels and whatnot. Alternatively you could take the values passed in and use them to immediately create the labels and buttons, set up the target actions and place them as subviews, that way you wouldn't need to keep the arguments as properties. Each button can be given a numerical tag so that you know whether or not the answer was correct or not (based on the integer passed into the initializer, which you *would* have to store somewhere). This is all from memory, but hopefully it's correct.

Comment: +1 to you since you've got a good grasp of what Nmzik is trying to do

Comment: +1 to you too for mentioning how he could store all his questions/answers.

Comment: Thanks ...."should have a custom initializer that takes five NSStrings (one for the question, four for the answers) and an integer to determine which answer is the correct one."how I can do it?????please help

Comment: I'll add an example to my original answer when I get the time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time creating 50 windows (if this is a MacOS question) or views (if this is an iOS question). Wow, that'd be awful.

Instead, create one single view which has four buttons and at least one label.

You can then populate the string values for each of those items from your list of questions & answers. You can keep those questions either in a plist file or a CoreData database or some parseable flat file, etc. Connect the four buttons to the (game?) controller via "`IBAction`" methods.